# NoMethodError: undefined method `add_attachment' for #<AddImageCloumnToPost:0x58 ba1b8>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, image-upload

In this application I am trying to do image upload. When I run the migration I am getting error.

Controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.save
  end

  def show
    @post=Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
  end

  def delete
  end

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:image)
  end
end
```

Model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_attached_file :image
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg",
     "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]            
end
```

Migration:

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end


class AddImageCloumnToPost < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_attachment :posts, :image
  end

  def down
    remove_attachment :posts, :image
  end
end
```

new.html.erb:

```
 <h1>Posts#new</h1>
  <%= form_for(@post, :html=>{ :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
  <%=   f.label :image %>
  <%= f.file_field :image %>
  <%= f.submit "Upload" %>
  <% end %>

  show.html.erb:

  <h1>Posts#Show</h1>
  <%= image_tag @post.image.url %>
```

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :posts
  get 'post/:id' => 'post#show'
  end
```

Error in console:

```
D:\imageupload>rake db:migrate
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
== 20150608132353 CreatePosts: migrating ======================================
-- create_table(:posts)
-> 0.0491s
== 20150608132353 CreatePosts: migrated (0.0491s) =============================

== 20150608132858 AddImageCloumnToPost: migrating =============================
-- add_attachment(:posts, :image)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `add_attachment' for #<AddImageCloumnToPost:0x58ba1b8>D:/imageupload/db/migrate/20150608132858_add_image_cloumn_to_post.rb:3:in `up'
C:in `migrate'
NoMethodError: undefined method `add_attachment' for #<AddImageCloumnToPost:0x58
ba1b8>
D:/imageupload/db/migrate/20150608132858_add_image_cloumn_to_post.rb:3:in `up'
C:in `migrate'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Not sure you needed to post your entire code for this. The error appears to be that in your migration it doesn't recognise `add_attachment`.

Comment: Run `rake db:migrate --trace` for better understanding of ERROR

Answer (score 1):

`add_attachment` is a helper method provided by `paperclip` gem to add columns which would contain `file_name`, `content_type`, `file_size` of the attachment.

As your error states, Rails has no idea on what this method means when you call it in your migration file:

```
undefined method `add_attachment' for #<AddImageCloumnToPost:0x58ba1b8>D:/imageupload/db/migrate/20150608132858_add_image_cloumn_to_post.rb:3
```

The most obvious reason for this behaviour is that you did not require `paperclip` gem properly. Refer to its [installation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#installation) section on github and don't forget to run `bundle install` before usage.

Answer (score 0):

`add_attachment` is provided by the [paperclip gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip). You would need to include that in your `Gemfile` and run `bundle install`.

Answer (score 0):

You missing `self`, Hope it helps

```
class AddImageCloumnToPost < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table :posts do |t|
      t.attachment :image
    end
  end

  def self.down
    remove_attachment :posts, :image
  end
end
```

Comment: You don't need `self` for later versions of rails (I think not since rails 2)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, it was because i was refering to older version of the paperclip gem. Make sure you are using the latest gem in your Gemfile.

```
gem "paperclip", "~> 4.2"
```